# xml parsing in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using mmenu library in jquery mobile, when parsing an xml and append the result to:

```
<nav></nav>
```

the sub-menus don't work correctly.

here is my js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


                 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "MainMenuAsXml.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(xml){
                    var list_elem = $("<ul></ul>");
                    $(xml).find('module').each(function(){
                        var module = $(this);
                        var moduleLabel = module.attr("text");
                        var directories_list = $("<li class='Selected'></li>").appendTo(list_elem);
                        module.find("directory").each(function(){
                            var directory = $(this);
                            var directoryLabel = directory.attr("text");
                            var directory_elem = $("<li></li>").append("<span>" + directoryLabel + "</span>").appendTo(directories_list);
                            var entries_list = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo(directory_elem);
                            directory.find("entries").each(function(){
                                var entries = $(this);
                                var linkName = entries.attr("text");
                                var myLink = entries.attr("link");
                                 $('<li><a href="#">' + linkName + '</a></li>' ).appendTo(entries_list);                        
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    $("#menu-left").append(list_elem));
                    buildMenu();
                  },
                  error: function() {
                    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
                  }
                  });
                });
</script>
```

I'm sure that the parsing result is correct but I think there is an error using the function.
and here is the output
[image]

Comment: ..hi i need ur help i want to do same parsing but in 3 level.. for example AA-->B-->B1. please how could i do it

Comment: it depends on your xml forma, i have module then directory then entries in my xml, the code above is for 3 levels so you can use it, but notice that i use mmenu lib so change the code if you do not.